# How to call an informatica workflow which running in different integration service

Tags: integration, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have 2 workflows workflow 1 in Integration service 1 and workflow 2 integration service 2.
How do I call workflow 2 from workflow 1 I am currently trying to call then using command prompt but it didn't work
Just to let you know these integration servicce 1 is informatica 9.2
and integration service 2 is informatica version 10.2

Comment: If they exis in same physical server, you shoild be able to do it. If its not then, You need to use remote shell command rsh to kick off a script (with pmcmd) in another integration service 2.

Comment: Thankyou for coming back to me do you have any example for the same . As i am not aware of rsh script

Answer (score 0):

PowerCenter does not provide suppor for cross-workflows dependencies. Regardless of whether these are configured to use same or a different Integration Service.

The best way to solve this kind of challenges is to use separate scheduling tool, such as AirFlow, Control-M, Autosys - or any other.

It is also possible to expose [the workflow as a webservice](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/web-services-provider-guide/working-with-web-service-workflows/creating-and-configuring-a-web-service-workflow/creating-a-web-service-workflow.html) and call it from different workflows, if needed. Not really convenitent, but possible.

Lastly, it's possible to use command line interface [pmcmd startworkflow](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/command-reference/pmcmd-command-reference/startworkflow.html) in a command task of one workflow to have the other one started.

Comment: I tried doing the pmcmd command but its failing pmcmd startask -service with error : Error: [Pre/Post Session Command] Process id 2739. The shell command failed with exit code 4.

Comment: The error is respect to node  1889
Message Code: LM_36621
Message: Command task instance [Command]: started command [Command1], with pid [3293] on node [node01_hjjk].

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar this way:

1. The other WF is a web service one/ or is executed along a web service.
2. Add an application connection.
3. The WSH where your WF runs should be the endpoint of that connection.
4. Add this WF inside the mapping of the other one as a Web Service transformation.